How to implement the setText function into my Stream React application
I am having trouble utilizing the setText function in my React chat application. I confirmed my project is updated to the latest Stream version (v12). On launching the app I get the following error:
MessageInputContext.js:8 The useMessageInputContext hook was called outside of the MessageInputContext provider. Make sure this hook is called within the MessageInput's UI component. The errored call is located in the undefined component.
And then without surprise I have this error code when clicking the button that utilizes the setText function:
Uncaught TypeError: setText is not a function
My sample code is included below:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  MessageList,
  MessageInput,
  Window,
  useChannelActionContext,
  Avatar,
  useChannelStateContext,
  useChatContext,
  useMessageInputContext
} from 'stream-chat-react';
import starIcon from '../assets/star-icon.png';
import bellIcon from '../assets/bell-icon.png';
import reservationIcon from '../assets/reservation-icon.png';

import { ChannelInfo } from '../assets';

const customersUI = require('./customerUI.json');
const customer = customersUI.customers[customersUI.customerChoice];
const restaurantName = customer.restaurantName;

const ChannelInner = ({ setIsEditing }) => {
  const [giphyState, setGiphyState] = useState(false);
  const { sendMessage } = useChannelActionContext();
  const { setText } = useMessageInputContext(); // Get the setText function from the context

  const overrideSubmitHandler = (message) => {
    let updatedMessage = {
      attachments: message.attachments,
      mentioned_users: message.mentioned_users,
      parent_id: message.parent?.id,
      parent: message.parent,
      text: message.text,
    };

    if (giphyState) {
      updatedMessage = { ...updatedMessage, text: `/giphy ${message.text}` };
    }

    if (sendMessage) {
      sendMessage(updatedMessage);
      setGiphyState(false);
    }
  };

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    // Use setText to update the value of the textarea
    setText('Hello from the button!');
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', width: '100%' }}>
      <Window>
        <TeamChannelHeader setIsEditing={setIsEditing} />
        <MessageList messageActions={['edit', 'delete']} />
        <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Click to set text in textarea</button>
        <MessageInput overrideSubmitHandler={overrideSubmitHandler} grow={true} />
      </Window>
      {/*<Thread />*/}
    </div>
  );
};

